# Proposition 5.4.4. in Tao

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove the following proposition in Tao's analysis textbook.

> For ever real number $x$, exactly one of the following three statements is true: (a) $x$ is zero; (b) $x$ is positive; (c) $x$ is negative. A real number $x$ is negative if and only if $-x$ is positive. If $x$ and $y$ are positive, then so are $x + y$ and $xy$.

I am unsure on how to approach the first part. Tao defines real numbers as limits of Cauchy sequences of rationals, though without defining just yet what a limit is. He defines a positive real number as one that can be written as the limit of a Cauchy sequence of rationals positively bounded away from $0$ and a negative real number as one that can be written as the limit of a Cauchy sequence negatively bounded away from $0$. We have a law of trichotomy for the rationals, which could be extended to every element of the sequence, perhaps, to say that, upon throwing out a finite number of terms, the sequence is either identically zero, positively bounded away from zero, or negatively bounded away from $0$, and thus $x$ is either $0$, positive, or negative. I am still unsure on how to formalize this, though, or whether I am on the right track.

The second statement seems rather straightforward. If $x$ is negative it is negatively bounded away from $0$: we have $x = \text{LIM}_{n \to \infty} a_n$, and $\exists - c < 0$ (-$c$ rational) such that $a_n \leq -c$, Therefore, $-x = \text{LIM}_{n \to \infty} -a_n$, where we have, multiplying through by $-1$, that $\exists c > 0$ such that $-a_n \geq c$, meaning $x$ is positively bounded away from $0$ and is therefore positive. The opposite implication is similar.

As for the third part: let $x = \text{LIM}_{n \to \infty} a_n$ and $y = \text{LIM}_{n \to \infty} b_n$. $x$ and $y$ are positive, meaning $a_n$ and $b_n$ are positively bounded away from $0$, so $\exists c > 0, a_n \geq c$ and $\exists d > 0, b_n \geq d$. Thus, for any $n$, $a_n + b_n \geq c + d$, and since the positive reals are closed under addition, $c + d > 0$ and $a_n + b_n$ is also positively bounded away from zero, so $x + y$ is also positive. The fourth part is similar, but with a product, $cd$, in lieu of a sum.

Assuming I have not made a mistake or omission, I believe that I understand how to write the later parts of the problem, but the first part is still quite confusing to me. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [messy] partial outline:

Let $y$ be a real number.

We'll do this in two parts: 1) show that $y$ can be labeled positive, negative, or 0
2) show that $y$ cannot be simultaneously: 0 and positive; 0 and negative; or positive and negative.

1) Suppose first that $y \not\equiv 0$. Then by Lemma $5.3.14$ [in my copy of the book]

> Let $x$ be a non-zero real number. Then $x=LIM_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n$ for some Cauchy sequence $(a_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ which is bounded away from zero.

So we can say $y=LIM_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n$, where there exists some rational $c>0$ such that for all $n$, $|a_n|\geq c$.

a) Suppose that $y$ is not negative. We'll show that $y$ must be positive.

> Lemma 1: Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be Cauchy. Fix $m$. Then the sequence $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, where $b_n=a_{m+n}$, is Cauchy and equivalent to $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

[The proof of this lemma relies on the epsilon-N definition of 'Cauchy'-ness]

Claim 1: There exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $a_n\geq c$.

Proof of Claim 1: First, we know that for all $N$, there must exist some $n\geq N$ such that $a_n>0$, since otherwise we would have some $N_0$ such that for all $n\geq N_0$, we have $a_n\leq -c<0$, and so $y=LIM (a_n)_{n=N_0}^{\infty}$, where the sequence $(a_n)_{n=N_0}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy and negatively bounded away from zero (making $y$ negative).

Now suppose the claim is false.

Then, for all $N$, there must be some $n1, n2\geq N$ such that $a_{n1}>c>0$ and $a_{n2}<-c<0$. Fix the $N_1$ such that for all $n, m\geq N_1$, $|a_n-a_m|<c/2$. But then our aforementioned $n1$ and $n2$ give us a contradiction, since $a_{n1}-a_{n2}>2c$.

This proves Claim 1.

Hence, by Lemma 1, $y=LIM (a_n)_{n=N}^{\infty}$, where the sequence $(a_n)_{n=N}^{\infty}$ is positively bounded away from zero.

b) Now suppose $y$ is not positive. We'll show that $y$ must be negative.
[the proof of this is similar to a]

So right now we know that any real $y$ must be at least one of: positive, negative, zero.

2) We now want to show $y$ cannot be more than one of our three options.

a) First, if $y=0=LIM b_n$, then for any $c>0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|b_n-0|=|b_n|<c$. So if $y=0$, $y$ cannot be bounded away from zero, and so $y$ cannot be positive or negative.

b) Now, let $y$ be positive. Then there exists a rational $c>0$ so that $y=LIM b_n$ for some sequence $b_n>c$. Since $0=LIM 0$, and we always have $|b_n-0|>c>0$, the sequences $(b_n)$ and $(0)$ cannot be equivalent, and so $y$ is nonzero. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $y$ is both negative and positive. Then there exists a rational $d>0$ such that $y=LIM e_n$ for some sequence such that $e_n<-d$ for all $n$. But then we have $|b_n-e_n|>c+d>0$ for all $n$, and so $b_n$ and $e_n$ cannot be equivalent sequences, a contradiction.

c) The case where $y$ is negative mimics 2b).